# nginx not redirecting to gunicorn while deploying flask application on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

gunicorn service file:

```
     [Unit]
     Description=Gunicorn instance for a simple hello world app
     After=network.target
     [Service]
     User=ubuntu
     Group=www-data
     WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/algotrading/oops
     ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/algotrading/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 wsgi:app
     Restart=always
     [Install]
     WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default file, proxy added

```
          location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

curl  http://127.0.0.1:8000/oops/configuration/fetchConfigurations?schema=oops1_v1_sit is working fine, but http://<public_ip>:8000/oops/configuration/fetchConfigurations?schema=oops1_v1_sit not working fine

Comment: We would need to see the rest of your nginx configuration to determine if that should be possible or not. Normally nginx listens on standard http/https ports (80/443) and then forwards to gunicorn on 8000. Meaning, don't use :8000 in combination with the public_ip.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this by replace user as root in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

Also another way you can setup nginx and gunicorn :

1. gunicorn.service file( Location : /etc/systemd/system/) :

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Gunicorn instance to serve algotrading
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=ubuntu
   Group=www-data
   WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/algotrading/oops
   Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/algotrading/venv/bin"
   ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/algotrading/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:algotrading.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

   Restart=always
   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Nginx Configuration File( Location : /etc/nginx/sites-available/) :

   ```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name <Public IP>;

     location / {
     include proxy_params;
     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/algotrading/oops/algotrading.sock;
    }
   }
   ```
3. Basic Commands :
   Start Gunicorn Service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo systemctl start algotrading
   sudo systemctl enable algotrading
   sudo systemctl status algotrading
   ```

Retstart nginx:
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`